# Messages-Based architecture with Windows Azure

Tags: .net, design-patterns, azure, message-queue

I am making web-based system on Windows Azure, which process orders from different sources - web-site or web-services. First thing appeared in my head was using Azure message queue from web-site and web-service Roles to some worker Role which will actually process orders.

I have found few articles about messages driven architecture with Azure and they looked fine - we are getting message from the client, put it to the queue and respond user "OK, your action was processed" after that worked thread will read that message and do all magic. **BUT here is an issue** - *if I want to send message's processing result (order Id if it was success and fail reason if not) as a response to the client than I need to wait till the Worker Role will process it*. The problem is that I did not find good/fast/cheap way to do that, *as a possible way* I can put message to the processing queue and check each X msecs if it was already processed or not (after processing, Worker will add information that message with Y Guid was processed together with results).

I don't really like idea with such waiting because time for order processing can be from few seconds to few minutes and it will be additional load on the system if each client (up to 10-20 at the same time) will check each X msec if his request was processed or not (main reason). Also it will be pretty expensive in view of Azure Tables access rate(minor reason).

**Can you advice some good way to implement that, please?** I am looking for something like Event waiting in the desktop apps, which cannot be made with Azure in view of highly distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking to do is have socket.io connections to the web server from the browser so you can respond instantly. There is a comet library for .NET, that I've never used, http://pokein.codeplex.com/. I've always done that part in Node.js, which is likely possible on Azure but might need some effort to get that running. Node has an awesome implementation for handling socket.io connections.

Web Request -> MQ -> Web Services -> Process Order -> Web Services on Web Server or MQ again -> Socket.io/comet -> web browser. All real time, as events happen.

If you let the use continue the browser the website, and just popped up a message that was like "you order has been processed, see the results here, when you are ready" the result is often pretty good.

Comment: Thank you @Travis for the suggestion, it looks pretty good for the web-site's part! But problem is that it will not work such good for the web-service's users, which are the bigest part of the system's users.

Comment: If you need to block to wait until it's complete, on .NET, I think you're stuck without rolling something of your own. It's going to eat up a thread polling or waiting for a response.

Comment: Finding way for such waiting is the reason of initial question - the problem is that #1 Role is putting message to the Azure Queue and the #2 Role is processing it and making result. So it's not so many ways to check from the #1 Role if the #2 Role did the job, one of them is checking Azure Table by the message Guid, but as I mentioned it's to expensive from costs and performance points of view (#1 Role will need to check Azure table periodically till the result will be made). The question if there a way for the #1 Role to subscribe to some event which will fire when #2 Role will did it's job?

Comment: http://www.nservicebus.com/ is an Enterprise Service Bus that would support this sort of thing (publish/subscribe messaging). Someone wrote connectors for Azure, so it should run on Azure just fine. There's also http://masstransit-project.com/, which is licensed more liberally, however, I'm not aware of any Azure transport connectors for it. (Might not be too hard to write though).

Answer (score 0):

The method that you've described is certainly what is usually recommended when doing this sort of thing.

The other way to do it is to have the role instances talk to each other directly.  If you're willing to use [App Fabric Queues](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabric/archive/2011/05/17/an-introduction-to-service-bus-queues.aspx) (still in CTP at the moment), then [this blog post](http://windowsazurecat.com/2011/08/how-to-simplify-scale-inter-role-communication-using-windows-azure-service-bus/) has a good description of setting up inter-role communication.

I'm sure this would have a similar outcome to the service bus options mentioned in other answers.

Comment: Thank you for the links, got a lot of ideas from them.

Answer (score 0):

Use TCP (Sockets) between the web role and the worker role.  If the request is likely to be slow then make it an asynchronous IIS request (e.g. use MVC AsyncController) and let a .Net thread handle the web role TCP code.  You can also go the whole hog and code the sockets asynchronously.

You will of course need to configure an internal endpoint on the worker role, and use the port that Azure allocates to it (see RoleEnvironment.Roles).

Comment: Intresting idea about Sockets between roles, I just need to check if Azure will not restrict such connections via Firewals - who knows, which architecture is using inside Data Center, I am afraid that I will be not able to open TCP connection just by knowing IP addr of the Role, because they are not static, I think.

Comment: If you use internal endpoints and the roles are in the same service, you can discover the ip address of these endpoints and talk to them quite happily.